# Equivalent of fn Convert in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the equievelent of this statement in oracle

```
SELECT {fn CONVERT(mycolumn, nvarchar) }
as MyConvertedColumn FROM MyTable;
```

according to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqfunc.htm)

it should be

```
SELECT {fn CONVERT('Groß', 'US7ASCII') }
"Conversion" FROM DUAL;
```

but that is not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mistake there, should be written:

```
SELECT CONVERT('Groß', 'US7ASCII') "Conversion" FROM DUAL;
```

in [11g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions034.htm#i77037) is ok.

Comment: 10000 plus for the answer, thanks. What character set to you advise me to use? utf8 or 'US7ASCII' ?

Comment: depends on what you want to do. With `UTF8` you'll not lose information.